# How can I get the multiple NFC record after launching the app by AAR

Tags: android, nfc, android-applicationrecord

After lauching the app by ARR, I read the intent and the intent has only ACTION.MAIN.

I follow the answer below but It doesn't work.

- [nfc-tag-is-null-when-more-than-1-ndefrecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741569/nfc-tag-is-null-when-more-than-1-ndefrecord)
- [application-launched-by-action-main-from-aar-instead-of-ndef-discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031682/application-launched-by-action-main-from-aar-instead-of-ndef-discovered)
- [android-nfc-start-app-using-aar-and-read-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082064/android-nfc-start-app-using-aar-and-read-text)

---

I write the mime-type data at first position in NFC tag and write the ARR-packagename at last position in NFC tag.

I also insert the intent-filter at manifest file

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/com.myorg.myapp" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21166441/2425802). Have you confirmed that your tag really contains a MIME type record with media type "application/com.myorg.myapp" as the *first* record of the NDEF message?

Comment: thanks for your comment. I already read this question and follow it. you can see the [content of nfc message](http://leonehouse.org:9000/files/11). could you see this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the app which read NFC tag must have two intent-filter sepearately
my intent-filter in Manifest.xml is below

```
<intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/org.leonehouse.nfc" />
        </intent-filter>
```